# How to make a macro open automatically when I start excel on mac os?

Tags: excel

I am trying out excel for MacOS and want to set up my Excel with some custom macros that I tied to keyboard shortcuts in my windows setup. I want the macros to be available any time I start excel.

To accomplish this in windows I put the relevant *.xlam files in the "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART" directory. Is there an equivalent directory for MacOS? Alternatively is there another method to accomplish the same goal?

Thanks! I've yet to find a good answer to this!

Running Catalina 10.15.2 and Excel 16.33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a directory to do the same as the PC by doing the following:

1. Click Excel in upper left and selecting Preferences
2. Select the General button
   [image: Image of Excel Preferences Pane]
3. Midway down the General Dialog Pane you will see a field that states the following: 'At startup, open all files in:' this is where you can choose a folder location and placed your Personal Workbook. Bottom line is that you choose your file location. That is actually the same as Windows. 
   [image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a bit confused. Do I need to name the file in that directory something specific? You mentioned personal workbook... is this the specific name, and if so does it matter if it's xls or xlam? Thanks!

Comment: The directory can be anywhere you want it to be. There’s no limitation. Just create the directory and browse to it to set the location. As for XLS/XLAM, whatever is in the directory will be opened. Many people call it personal.xlam but it can be anything. The being said, a lot of people who use this approach of auto open set their workbook to be hidden when it opens. You can still access the macros via the developer tab.